# Objective c: how to call a main method in a library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've got a library I inherited from another team and can't modify because it's in use by others. That library has a main method in it that starts its processing.

Library's main.c
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])

My app's main.m

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

Is it possible to rename main in my objective c project and have that launched when the app starts?

In C# I could do this:

```
private delegate void mainDelegate(int argc, string[] argv);
public Delegate LoadFunction<T>(string dllPath, string functionName)
{
    var hModule = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
    if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    var functionAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
    return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionAddress, typeof(T));
}

// initialize with
main = (mainDelegate)LoadFunction<mainDelegate>(AppFile, "main");

// call with 
main(0x0, null);
```

If not, is it possible to call the specific library's main method without it colliding with mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html), "The entry point for every C-based app is the `main` function and iOS apps are no different."

From this, I would understand there can only be one `main` function.